# If quoting only an extract of dialogue from a fiction book, do you still need to have quotes within quotes?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, quotation-marks, citation, dialogue

I need to show kids how to write a book review. I am writing a book review as an exemplar to show them how it's done. However, I got stuck when it came to citing extracts of dialogue. My question is in two parts.

**1. Quoting an extract of dialogue**

If you are quoting only an extract of dialogue, should you use quotes within quotes? Here is the extract from the book. The words I would like to quote are in bold.

> 'You sure you can't eat it, love?' said Ma. 'You look **like a match with the wood scraped off**.'

This is how I've included the quote in the book review. (Note that I am  using the UK style of single quotes.)

> 1A. Ma describes Barbara as 'a match with the wood scraped off' (p58).

Is this correct? Or, because I am quoting dialogue, should I use quotes within quotes:

> 1B. Ma describes Barbara as '"a match with the wood scraped off"' (p58).

**2. Quoting an entire sentence of a character's dialogue**

If you are quoting an entire sentence of a character's dialogue, do you use quotes within quotes? Here is the extract from the book. The words I would like to quote are in bold:

> Barbara caught the towel. '**There's no such thing as women's work and men's work.** They should both look after the kids.'

This is how the quote appears in my book review.

> 2A. Barbara expresses many modern ideas. For example, she tells Elaine: 'There's no such thing as women's work and men's work' (p67).

Have I punctuated the dialogue correctly? Or should I use quotes within quotes:

> 2B. Barbara expresses many modern ideas. For example, she tells Elaine: '"There's no such thing as women's work and men's work"' (p67).

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: This belongs on [writers.se].

Comment: No, no, don't use quotes within quotes in these cases; that can't be right. This is a style issue, not a grammar issue, and different style guides give different recommendations. But I've never seen any style guide recommend this. The important thing with any matter of style, though, is that once you've made your choice, be consistent.

Comment: Hey William, thanks for your reply. Have you seen a style guide that has explicitly stated that it is OK to use one set of quotes when quoting an extract of dialogue? If so, could you point me to that style guide?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about style, not a question about English Language & Usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance Examples 1A and 2A are perfect.

Even though the extracted dialogue was from a verbal conversation, it does not require a second pair of quotation marks - they would be redundant.

However, if the conversation made reference to someone or something else saying something then you would need to surround the quote with two sets of quotation marks.

> e.g. 'Hey! Look at this! It says: "~quote here~".'

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is **indenting**, as it wholly dispenses with quotes:

Barbara expresses many modern ideas. [She tells Elaine:]

```
         There's no such thing as women's work and men's work (p67).
```

**[EDIT]** If not that, 1A and 2A, then. As a matter of fact, this isn't quite a full/two-sided dialogue you are quoting, as you seem to be quoting only one of the speakers.

For full dialogues, see [The Wadsworth Guide to MLA Documentation, MLA Update](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pZ4IAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA243&dq=%22quoting%20dialogue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qHIbVcyMLsqUNrSagLgD&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22quoting%20dialogue%22&f=false), the  [Wiley AP English Literature and Composition](https://books.google.ca/books?id=fEBfvJXcEUUC&pg=PT207&dq=%22quoting%20dialogue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qHIbVcyMLsqUNrSagLgD&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22quoting%20dialogue%22&f=false), or any of the other references  [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22spout%20embarrassing%20platitude%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=j3IbVafrD8GlNuLogYAM#tbm=bks&q=%22quoting%20dialogue%22).

Comment: Thanks Marius. I am following the style where only larger pieces of text are indented.  I am reluctant to break this consistency, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Katy Forde: Added to my answer.